# Why is my power out?

Tags: electrical

We got our electric shut off so we played the bill called electric company they said to turn off main switch so we did. They turned power on so we switched it on and still no power. We took off main switch put new one on and still no power. What would it be?

Comment: many things are possible including a loose connection in your panel.  you need an electrician to open the panel and check ... after you look at the meter to be sure the power company hooked you back up right.  once they cut my power because an apartment neighbor did not pay their bill.  they can make mistakes like that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not possible to accurately answer it, without actually being on site.

Answer (score 3):

Tell your utility to come back out, as it sounds like something in the meter base got undone; either that, or your service drop/lateral's bad.  Either way, it's the utility's job to fix.